# Failed to parse date ["2016-08-29 11:08:37.645007"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' '

Tags: java, gson, simpledateformat, date-format, timezone-offset

i have jsondata in which one of the field is date and its value looks like

"2016-08-29 11:08:37.645007" i using gson to get the deserialized object from json
but it throws following execetion

`

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2016-08-29 11:08:37.645007"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:149)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:245)
    ... 65 more
```

`

im not sure what should be the format of date tried `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` but it didnt work

Comment: there is really no time zone indicator in the input.... what does "645007" stand for? millionth of a second?

Comment: what you have tried post it here.??

Comment: Did you look up the Javadocs to see what the format ought to be?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also there is no way `SimpleDateFormat` can parse you 6 decimals of fraction of second. It supports only millisecond precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date you're trying to parse doesn't contain a timezone.
Try the format string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

Comment: yes it doesnt has the time zone info and had some redundant info along with the date